# How does the setw stream manipulator work?

Tags: c++, setw

How does the `setw` **stream manipulator (space count)** work? When there is one `\t`, for example, I want to print `a` with four spaces, so I use `\t` and I compare `\t` with `setw`.

The code that I wrote:

```cpp
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"\t"<<"a\n";
    std::cout<<std::setw(9)<<"a\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
   a // This is 1 '\t'
   a // This is setw()
```

So what I **thought** was:

`setw(18)` = `\t\t`

The code worked. But when I deleted the `\n`, it did not become one straight line.

```cpp
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"\t\t"<<"a\n";
    std::cout<<std::setw(18)<<"a";
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me this output:

```
      a
       a
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Tabs and width adjusting is ***not*** the same. Tab typically goes to fixed positions in the terminal, usually 8, 16, 24, etc. The newline should not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you need to add a `\n` at the `setw(18)`. **And this applies to any `setw`.**

Sample code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>
int main()
{
std::cout<<"\t\t"<<"a\n";
std::cout<<std::setw(18)<<"a\n"; // And you add the \n here
return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
        a
        a
```

And another solution is:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>
int main()
{
std::cout<<"\t\t"<<"a\n";
std::cout<<std::setw(18)<<"a "; // And you add the a space here
return 0;
}
```

And the output will be **the same.**

---

The reason behind why should we put the `\n` or a space is because:

> It's because it justifies the whole two-character string `"a"\n`, not only the `a`. If you print the newline separately (... << 'a' << '\n') then you would get the same "error". You could also have solved it by using almost any space character, like ... << "a "; You might want to **print both with and without the newline in the same program to see the difference.** - Some Programmer Dude

Comment: Do you know *why* the newline matter here? It's because it justifies the whole two-character string `"a\n"`, not only the `a`. If you print the newline separately (`... << 'a' << '\n'`) then you would get the same "error". You could also have solved it by using almost *any* space character, like `... << "a ";` You might want to print both with and without the newline in the same program to see the difference.